# AudioKit : reload audio files in sampler

Tags: ios, audiokit

I must play an audio loop continuously and be able to reload the audio file on the fly, without interruption. I already tried these solutions :

- use AKAudioPlayer and its "replace(file:)" method -> problem : the replace file is super slow (1 sec) as well as the "play" method.
- use AKSampler ->   problem : the AKSampler seems not to be able to replace audio file on the fly, so I must create a new one, stop the audio engine, reconnect the AKSampler, restart the audio engine (super slow)

Is there a more obvious solution I would have missed ?

Comment: could you preload the files and use a mixer?

Comment: ok I did that. I thought it would be more obvious. It's basically impossible to build easily a realtime looper with AudioKit (at least with AKAudioPlayer and AKSampler)

Comment: would you care to vote my answer as accepted using the green check to the left? thx

Answer (score 0):

Preload the files and use a mixer.